# Concat nth elements of two list

Tags: c#

is there a another way of doing this

```
 ab = ("A" "B" "C" "D")
 cd = ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")

        for (int i = 0; i < ab.Count; i++)
    {
        ef.Add(ab[i] + cd[i]);
    }

     ef ("Aa" "Bb" "Cc" "Dd")
```

Like in lisp that does not require an index number

```
(mapcar (function (lambda (a b)
        (strcat a b))) ab cd)
```

more than two lists

```
(mapcar (function (lambda (a b)
        (strcat a b))) ab cd ef gh ij)
```

Comment: Thank you both, question though, say i  want to be able to add another string between the two elements  like in the above lisp sample (strcat a "word" b))).

Comment: or even use 3 or more lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ef = ab.Zip(cd, (x, y) => x + y);
```

`ef` will be an `IEnumerable<string>` (deferred).  If you need a `List<string>` then add `.ToList()` to the result of the `Zip()` invocation.

Comment: @pBe So use `x + "other string" + y` then.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Zip function.  You can find documentation on this  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx). The example they provide is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Nice.. Thank you kolichikov